# About positive negatives use

Tags: difference, negation, emphasis

Please take a look at the following example:

> Let's see if we can't get there before they get back.

I'm pretty sure the sentence is grammatical and its semantic is quite similar to:

> Let's see if we can get there before they get back.

But then what's the point of using the first version?

In my language the situation is similar and we use it as the speaker is giving the sentence extra emphasis by using the negative form.

Consequently, by checking if the opposite of one thing is impossible then the thing we want to do must be possible.

What about in English? Please let me know your thoughts on this.

Comment: Nice question. I think it is a periphrasis for **try** which presents the possibility of failure as a challenge, to elicit best efforts.  *Let's **try hard** to get there before they get back.*

Comment: So, a literary device, right, @Tᴚoɯɐuo ?

Comment: No, not literary. It's definitely colloquial.

Comment: Oh, l see... @Tᴚoɯɐuo.

Comment: It is a way of inviting a "buy-in" to the goal.  It might be paraphrased as "C'mon..." that is, "Come on".

Comment: It can also be a way of indicating that you intend to try your best. At a hotel check-in desk, the words  *Let's see if we can't find you a room* would sound a shade better to the would-be guest than *Let's see if we can find you a room.*

Comment: To me "let's see if we can't" is a matter of getting lost in the sentence and not parsing it properly. It sounds like "I could care less" instead of "I couldn't care less".

Comment: @GreenGrassoHolm, intriguingly, I thought it's a natural way in spoken English, exactly the way it's in my language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's trying to convey that you are going to be making the attempt that could fail but *might* not. They are saying we *might as well* try to beat the others to getting there first.